# adding record from database to array for ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

This is my php file

```
<?php
  $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

//Select db
mysql_select_db("learn"); ?>
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
        $row=array();
        $user = $_GET['user'];  
        $qu = "SELECT username from users where username= ".$user;
        $sel=mysql_query($qu,$con);
        if($sel) 
        { 
        $row[]= mysql_fetch_row($sel); 
        }


        if(in_array($user,$row))
                echo ' '.$user.' is  available';
                elseif($user=='')
                        echo 'Enter username';
                else
                        echo 'Username ' .$user.' is available';

echo '</response>';


?>
```

I want to add username to an array `$row` so that when existing record is present it shows username not available.

The above code only shows username available  even if same username exists in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are already querying

```
"SELECT username from users where username= ".$user
```

so you can just do a

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sel)>0) {
      //user name exists do something
}
```

and figure out the username is available or not.

#### note:

Also keep in mind that your code is prone to mysql injection and the driver you are using is deprecated as of now. Prefer `PDO` or `mysqli`

#### update:

Your existing code can be corrected as

```
$user = $_GET['user'];  

if($user=='') {

    echo 'please enter a username';

} else {

    $sel=mysql_query("SELECT username from users where username= '".$user."'",$con);

    if(mysql_num_rows($sel) > 0) {
        
        echo 'Username ' .$user.' is not available';
        
    } else {

        echo 'Username ' .$user.' is available';

    }

}
```